# c# remove 3rd party application from taskbar

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, hide, taskbar

How to remove an 3rd party application from the Windows taskbar by its handle?

I've found this:
[Remove application from taskbar with C# wrapper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157712/remove-application-from-taskbar-with-c-sharp-wrapper)

But it doesnt worked for me.
It only sets another style (small x to close, no maximize/minimize button) to the Window i selected (notepad).

Any ideas about this?

**EDIT: I dont want to remove MY application from the taskbar, i want to remove an external application by handle**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Win32: How to hide 3rd party windows in taskbar by hWnd](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7219063/win32-how-to-hide-3rd-party-windows-in-taskbar-by-hwnd)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have the handle to the window you can call [`ShowWindow()`](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/ShowWindow.html) through the Win32 API. Then you can do:

```
// Let the window disappear (even from taskbar)
ShowWindow(this.Handle, WindowShowStyle.Hide);

// Revive the window back to the user
ShowWindow(this.Handle, WindowShowStyle.ShowNoActivate);
```

So from now, all your problem is to get the handle of the window you like to hide:

```
Process[] procs = Process.GetProcesses();
IntPtr hWnd;
foreach(Process proc in procs)
{
   if ((hWnd = proc.MainWindowHandle) != IntPtr.Zero)
   {
      Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", proc.ProcessName, hWnd);
   }
}
```

Comment: this doesnt worked for me. after hiding the windows they are invisible, after setting shownoactivate they are visible again but also shown in the taskbar.

Comment: @user1216595: Ok, i misunderstood you. You want to see the window, but it should not appear within the taskbar. I thought you would like to hide the window (like minimize) AND remove it from the taskbar.

Comment: @user1216595: In that case [this question has already been answered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7219063/win32-how-to-hide-3rd-party-windows-in-taskbar-by-hwnd).

Comment: this aint restore :                 IntPtr hWnd = p[0].MainWindowHandle;

                ShowWindow(hWnd, WindowShowStyle.ShowNoActivate);

Answer (score 4):

To hide it from windows task bar you just need to set ShowInTaskbar property to false :

```
this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
```

As for moving of windows you can use [spy++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163617.aspx) to check windows events and identify it.

Answer (score 0):

How to remove an application from the Windows taskbar?

```
this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
```

Answer (score -3):

Easy:

```
this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
```

As for the **Form** movement: you can use the `Move` event under **Layout events**